# trying to drag and drop over different columns but it is failing

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have coded this to implement drag and drop and came up with this, there are a few glitches in this:

- Unable to move element properly, if I move second one, it always move first one
- I am open to use `jquery` or UI because I want to create a clickable code to the elements which are on the columns so I can open `colorbox` to open it when need

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/colorbox.css"/>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
<script src="assets/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>
<style>
#div1, #div2,#div3,#div4,#div5,#div6 {
    float: left;
    width: 180px;
    height: 70vh;
    margin: 1px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background:#ccc;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Drag and Drop</h2>
<div><a href="javascript:;" class="openlead" data-url="addlead.php">Add New Lead</a></div>
<hr/>
<div class="container">

    <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">

            <div draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1">boo</div>  <hr> 

            <div draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1">K</div>  <hr> 

    </div> 

    <div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">

    </div> 

    <div id="div3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">

    </div> 

    <div id="div4" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">

    </div> 

    <div id="div5" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">

    </div> 

    <div id="div6" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">

    </div> 

</div>
</body>
<script>
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
$(document).on('click','.openlead',function() {
    $.colorbox({iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"80%", href: $(this).data('url')});
});
</script>
</html>
```

The code has all the Page I had coded till now, I have it to the 6 columns and I should be able to move back and forth

Comment: Are these all lists and you're moving items from list to list? It's not clear what the goal is of the drag and drop feature.

Comment: Also, you have 2 drag items of the same ID: `drag1`. This may cause an issue for you.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to cosnider using Sortable. Please review: http://jqueryui.com/sortable/

Here is an example.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".openlead").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.colorbox({
      iframe: true,
      width: "80%",
      height: "80%",
      href: $(this).data('url')
    });
  });
  $(".box").sortable({
    items: "> .item",
    connectWith: "div.box"
  })
});
```

```css
.box {
  float: left;
  width: 180px;
  height: 70vh;
  margin: 1px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: #ccc;
}

.item {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #EEE;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/colorbox.css" />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.colorbox/1.6.4/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>
<h2>Drag and Drop</h2>
<div>
  <a class="openlead" data-url="addlead.php">Add New Lead</a>
</div>
<hr/>
<div class="container">
  <div id="div-1" class="box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <div id="drag-1" class="item">Book</div>
    <div id="drag-2" class="item">Title</div>
  </div>
  <div id="div-2" class="box">
  </div>
  <div id="div-3" class="box">
  </div>
  <div id="div-4" class="box">
  </div>
  <div id="div-5" class="box">
  </div>
  <div id="div-6" class="box">
  </div>
</div>
```